# gRPC web + envoy + Spring boot GRPC server - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: grpc-java, envoyproxy, grpc-web, envoyer.io

gRPC server ( has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource)

- Started the gRPC server(https://github.com/vinsguru/vinsguru-blog-code-samples/tree/master/grpc/grpc-web/server) which is running on the 6565 port
- Started envoy server with below configuration

> ```
> static_resources:
>   listeners:
>   - address:
>       socket_address:
>         address: 0.0.0.0
>         port_value: 8080
>     filter_chains:
>     - filters:
>       - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
>         typed_config:
>           "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
>           codec_type: AUTO
>           stat_prefix: ingress_http
>           access_log:
>           - name: envoy.access_loggers.stdout
>             typed_config:
>               "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.stream.v3.StdoutAccessLog
>           route_config:
>             name: local_route
>             virtual_hosts:
>             - name: backend
>               domains:
>               - "*"
>               routes:
>               - match:
>                   prefix: "/"
>                   grpc: {}
>                 route:
>                   cluster: backend_grpc_service
>               cors:
>                   allow_origin_string_match:
>                   - prefix: "*"
>                   - safe_regex:
>                       google_re2: {}
>                       regex: \*
>                   allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
>                   allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout,Access-Control-Allow-Origin
>                   max_age: "1728000"
>                   expose_headers: grpc-status,grpc-message
>           http_filters:
>               - name: envoy.grpc_web
>                 typed_config:
>                   "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.grpc_web.v3.GrpcWeb
>               - name: envoy.cors
>                 typed_config:
>                   "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.cors.v3.Cors
>               - name: envoy.filters.http.router
>                 typed_config:
>                   "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
>
>
>   clusters:
>   - name: backend_grpc_service
>     type: STRICT_DNS
>     lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
>     typed_extension_protocol_options:
>       envoy.extensions.upstreams.http.v3.HttpProtocolOptions:
>         "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.upstreams.http.v3.HttpProtocolOptions
>         explicit_http_config:
>           http2_protocol_options: {}
>     load_assignment:
>       cluster_name: backend_grpc_service
>       endpoints:
>       - lb_endpoints:
>         - endpoint:
>             address:
>               socket_address:
>                 address: localhost
>                 port_value: 6565
> ```

- Started the grpcWebClient (https://github.com/vinsguru/vinsguru-blog-code-samples/tree/master/grpc/grpc-web/client)
- Opened the browser upon performing client operations I get below errors

Allowing all origins with below snippet, But it throws an error with Access-Control-Allow-Origin not present

> allow_origin_string_match:
> - prefix: "*"

Browser console log

```
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/calculator.CalculatorService/findSquare' from origin 'http://localhost:8811' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
bundle.js:1136 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getResult')
```

Comment: Hi. I wonder if you could follow the HelloWorld example which uses a similar Envoy config, and see where's the main difference between that and your setup?

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/tree/master/net/grpc/gateway/examples/helloworld#configure-the-proxy

thanks :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sampajano, will check it might be helping me with this example

Comment: I'm having this same issue too; how did you solve it?